# CSS mouse click area on text links too large in Chrome & Safari

Tags: css

I believe there is something in the CSS file that is causing Chrome and Safari to create extra large mouse over areas on all the text links. This is not happening with IE or Firefox. Can anyone give me a tip on what is wrong with the CSS? The mouse changes to the pointer way outside of the normal bounds around the link. Thank you for your help.

Page with problem: http://developer4you.net

Comment: Please post your CSS and HTML specific to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: No problem here.. I cant downvote yet, but..

Comment: Take out that Span Tag and margin on the A tag.

Comment: It's somehow the Camria Math font-family that causes this. Deactivate it in body and there you go. What's wrong with the font I don't know. But since it is a math font it might have an internal height you cannot see, but some browser act like it has this line-height.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem by narrowing down the CSS to just a few lines. Then include it in your question or via some code sharing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks goes to yunzen!

If you use the Cambria Math font in your CSS, some borwsers (i.e Chrome and Safari) will locate the clickable area outside of the normal click zone bounds on `<a>` elements. This makes the page non-user friendly. Stackoverflow rocks and thanks again yunzen!

Comment: I am changing the CSS to use a different font so the original link wont show the error. I hope you don't take this as spam, but there really is an issue with the Cambria Math font that is now resolved thanks to yunzen's answer. Omit it and use another font.